# How to concatenate strings within a br in python XPath?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Trying to solve how to concatenate strings  within a `<br>` is not working.

Here is the code:

```
<li class="attr">
    <span>
        Size:L
        <br>
        Color:RED
    </span>
</li>
```

I tried using these but is not working:

```
color_and_size = row.xpath('.//li[@class="attr"][1]/span[1]/text()')[0]
```

Comment: What do you mean by within `<br>`? Can you give a sample of the output you want?

Comment: i want the "Size:L" and "Color:RED" be printed

Comment: That's not valid `XML` as your `<BR>` tag isn't closed. So you won't be able to use an `xpath` expression against it.

Comment: "is not working" is an under-statement with that input. That would likely end noisy or do you use a `try-except` clause?

Comment: You shouldn't really use xpath for HTML documents, try `BeautifulSoup` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your xml structure is corrupt since no closing `</br>` tag- So if you use `lxml` then try [soupparser](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) that use Beautifulsoup- Or you can use standalone Beutifulsoup as below-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<li class="attr">
    <span>
        Size:L
        <br>
        Color:RED
    </span>
</li>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

print map(lambda x: x.text.strip().replace("\n",""),soup.find_all('span'))
```

Prints-

```
[u'Size:L                Color:RED']
```

N.B. Beautifulsoup organises xml internally e.g. if you want valid xml of your malformed xml then try-

```
print soup.prettify()
```

Prints-

```
<html>
 <body>
  <li class="attr">
   <span>
    Size:L
    <br/>
    Color:RED
   </span>
  </li>
 </body>
</html>
```

If your `xml` was valid the below `xpath` would work-

`//li[@class='attr']/span/text()[preceding-sibling::br or following-sibling::br]`

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/467bdd7d5a59eb29289d08ea3eca9951)</kbd> **Just click the** `Test` **button**

Answer (score 1):

You can combine Python string methods with `lxml`'s XPath return values:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> text = '''<html>
... <li class="attr">
...     <span>
...         Size:L
...         <br>
...         Color:RED
...     </span>
... </li>
... </html>'''
>>> doc = lxml.html.fromstring(text)
>>>
>>> # text nodes can contain leading and trailing whitespace characters
>>> doc.xpath('.//li[@class="attr"]/span[1]/text()')
['\n        Size:L\n        ', '\n        Color:RED\n    ']
>>> 
>>> # you can use Python's strip() method
>>> [t.strip() for t in doc.xpath('.//li[@class="attr"]/span[1]/text()')]
['Size:L', 'Color:RED']
```

You can also test the `<span>` if it contains a `<br>`: (`span[br]` instead of `span[1]`)

```
>>> doc.xpath('.//li[@class="attr"]/span[br]/text()')
['\n        Size:L\n        ', '\n        Color:RED\n    ']
>>> [t.strip() for t in doc.xpath('.//li[@class="attr"]/span[br]/text()')]
['Size:L', 'Color:RED']
>>>
```